# How to set "capped" after collection is created?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to set a `capped` parameter to my collection within my mongoose.Schema that did not include `capped` at first.
Any help welcome.

My Schema:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var userSchema = new Schema({
        name:  { type: String, required: true },
        email: { type: String },
        password: { type: String },
        isAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false},
        avatar: { type: String },
        joinDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    },{ autoCreate: true, capped : 1024})

userSchema.set('timestamps', true);
const Users = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema)
module.exports = Users;
```

I get following error:

```
Error: A non-capped collection exists with the name: users  
To use this collection as a capped collection, please first convert it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have already created a `users` collection in your database. So to convert it into a capped run below command either in `mongoshell` or `robomongo`

```
db.runCommand( { convertToCapped: 'users', size: 1024 } )
```